# How to integrate ReSharper and Teamcity?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, teamcity

I am currently using Visual Studio 2008 and ReSharper 5.0. Would like to know after installing the plugin for TeamCity with Visual Studio, how can I integrate ReSharper and Teamcity, since both are under JetBrains. And would like to know how ReSharper and TeamCity can work together to improve finding errors once the code cannot compile together?

Comment: The two products' feature sets don't really overlap. ReSharper is about editing code; TeamCity is about builds. What is it you want to integrate?

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper doesn't currently integrate with TeamCity.
Relevant feature requests in JetBrains issue tracker include [RSRP-162275: Standalone command-line tool to run inspections etc, to plug in to build-script](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-162275) and [TW-11084: Integration for ReSharper command-line inspections tool](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-11084)

Comment: But I realized it can integrate with NUnit. But is the integration with visual studio enough? I would like to have  immediate tracking of unit test results. I am trying to do unit testing, so if I make any changes to my code, I want the project to sync with TeamCity and have immediate checking of the project for any bugs.

Comment: Here is the link i saw On the integration http://blogs.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2010/09/20/vs_addin_resharper/

Comment: You had initially inquired whether the two tools work together in terms of error detection. The answer is that they don't. In terms of unit testing, both ReSharper and TeamCity are able to run unit tests: ReSharper does that locally on demand whereas TeamCity does that remotely on schedule after building. Immediate tracking of unit test results is normally what you're able to achieve by running tests in ReSharper.

Comment: That said, I don't think I understand clearly what you're trying to achieve. If your project large? Do you know for sure which tests cover which code?